# Use ehcache to implement a multimap

Tags: ehcache, multimap

Is it possible to use ehcache to implement a multimap?  I would like to store duplicate keys that store different values and expire after a given time.  Ehcache can easily handle the expiration of elements, but I am not aware of a configuration to allow duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehcache does not support duplicate keys. You could always cache a collection of values as long as a single expiration for all values makes sense.

Comment: Thank you.  This is actually what I was thinking as well.  It's not perfect, but it should work given the specific use-case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [infinispan](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan) in this

```
    @Test
    public void testMultimapCache() throws Exception {
        EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(Environment.openClasspathResource("/infinispan.xml"));
        MultimapCacheManager<String, Object> multimapCacheManager = EmbeddedMultimapCacheManagerFactory.from(cacheManager);
        MultimapCache<String, Object> cache = multimapCacheManager.get("test");
        cache.put("a", new Integer(1));
        cache.put("a", new Integer(2));
        cache.put("a", new Integer(3));
        cache.put("a", new Integer(4));
        cache.put("a", new Integer(1));
        System.out.println(cache.get("a").get());
        // [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
```